# How to get permalink and title from post ID?

Tags: permalinks, title, array, php, id

I have stored an array of post IDs and I would like to list the posts as links, meaning I need to get the title and permalink for the post ID - $id. The list should be echoed out by the following if condition, which means I somehow have to replace $id with the permalink and title. At the moment the code merely lists the post ID numbers.

```
<?php
  if(count($related)){
    echo "<div>Read More<ul>";
    foreach($related as $id){
       echo "<li>$id</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<?php
if(count($related)) {
    echo "<div>Read More<ul>";
    foreach($related as $id) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a></li>';
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your answer...it's genius! :D

Answer (score 10):

You just need to use `get_permalink( $id )` and `get_the_title( $id )`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have access you could try the wp api

`https://content.wordpress.com.au/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/POST_ID`